# How to get TypeDef from TypeSpec

Tags: c#, .net, metadata, clr, cil

I'm trying to implement managed debugger looking at MDBG sample.
Currently I'm stuck trying to get base class hierarchy methods using IMetaDataImport.

[EnumMethods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231658(v=vs.110).aspx), that I'm using, enumerates MethodDef tokens representing methods of the **specified type**. But I want to enumerate all the methods in class hierarchy. To do that I'm using GetTypeDefProps, that returns ptkExtends, which is token representing the base class. The problem is that base class could be represented by TypeDef, TypeRef or TypeSpec.

How can I get base class TypeDef from relative TypeSpec?

I've read ECMA part II specifications, but it didn't help me a lot...

Here is what I got so far:

```
      int size;                    
      TypeAttributes pdwTypeDefFlags;
      m_importer.GetTypeDefProps(m_typeToken,
                    null,
                    0,
                    out size,
                    out pdwTypeDefFlags,
                    out ptkExtends
                    );

      //ptkExtends is correct TypeSpec token
      IntPtr ppvSig;
      uint pcbSig;
      m_importer.GetTypeSpecFromToken(ptkExtends, out ppvSig, out pcbSig);
      //I'm getting the TypeSpec Blob signature in ppvSig, how to use it to get TypeDef?!
```

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? Whenever I call `GetTypeSpecFromToken` I do get an AccessViolationException. Though I get a Type when using the ptkExtends its name are some strange Unicode characters and the Methods returned are the same as on the base type.

Comment: @toATwork At some point the answer Brian gave bellow helped me to get this working, unfortunately it was quite long time ago, so I don't remember the details anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated previously, the TypeSpec format is defined in Partition II Section 23.2.14, its expressed with something resembling EBNF with the terminals defined in section 23.1.16.

A TypeSpec can represent a range of different kinds of types, but the only one that makes sense for a base class is `GENERICINST` (a closed generic type).

```
TypeSpecBlob ::= GENERICINST (CLASS | VALUETYPE) TypeDefOrRefEncoded GenArgCount Type Type*
             | ...
```

`TypeDefOrRefEncoded` is defined in section 23.2.8, compressed integers are defined at the start of section 23.2 and `Type` is defined in section 23.2.12.

```
Type ::= CLASS TypeDefOrRefEncoded
     | VALUETYPE TypeDefOrRefEncoded
     | ...
```

Given the bytes from your previous example (`15 12 3C 01 12 36`), my 'back of the napkin' scratching's come up with the following:

```
15 // GENERICINST
12 //   CLASS
3C //     TypeDefOrRefEncoded = 0200000F (The TypeDef of the open generic type.)
01 //   GenArgCount = 1
12 //   CLASS
36 //     TypeDefOrRefEncoded = 0100000D (The TypeRef of the single type argument.)
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it now! it's the 3rd parameter that I'm interested in!

Comment: The metadata token you are after is the first one (the open generic type as opposed to the type arguments). You could simplify the entire thing to "verify that the first byte is 0x15 and that the second byte is 0x11 or 0x12" and then read the TypeDefOrRefEncoded to get your metadata token..

Comment: Ok, I understood the idea and can dig dipper into specification to check all the cases, but probably it will break down to the check you mentioned. One more thing, the token is encoded, is there any standard way to decode it? I mean using some Framework Class Library?

Comment: I am not aware of anything exposed by the framework to do it for you. I wouldn't be surprised if Mono had something, but I never bother to check, I have always just done it myself (it's really not that complicated - my method to read a compressed uint is less than 40 lines, with error checking).